# ダウンロードして来たライブラリをcmakeを使ってPCにインストールする手順が知りたい。

Tags: c++, cmake

###### 試したこと

参考画像のglmディレクトリを見ましたがINSTALLソリューションがあるだけでx64はvisual studioの関連ファイルしかりません。

###### 知りたいこと

cmakeを使ってダウンロードして来たライブラリをPCにインストールして使えるようになるまでの手順が知りたい(インクルードできるファイルを生成する手順)生成したライブラリデータなどが見当たらないのですがこれはどうなっているのでしょうか？
　調べましたが自分で作ったソースコードをcmake すうる方法しか書かれていないので方法がわかりません。

###### ダウンロードして来たライブラリ

Github: https://github.com/g-truc/glm

###### やっとこと

cmake GUI版を使って新しく作ったbuildディレクトリを選択してconfigureしてgenerateとしてopen projectをクリックしてリリースモード x64を選択してINSTALLソリューションで右クリックしてビルドをクリックしました。下記画像がbuildディレクトリです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

質問文には「使えるようになるまでの手順が知りたい」とはありますが、具体的には何を実現したいのか（何が実現できれば使えるようになったと判断できるのか）が書かれていませんでした。

とはいえ [GLM 0.9.9 Manual / 1. Getting started](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/0.9.9.8/manual.md#-11-using-global-headers) には

> GLM is a header-only library, and **thus does not need to be compiled**. We can use GLM's implementation of GLSL's mathematics functionality by including the `<glm/glm.hpp>` header:
>
> ```
> #include <glm/glm.hpp>
> ```

とあります。これで解決しますでしょうか？

---

> インクルードできるファイルを生成する手順

「thus does not need to be compiled」とありますようにコンパイル、ビルド、生成などの操作は不要です。リポジトリそのまま、もしくはリリースページにあるzipを解凍した状態で使えます。

Comment: いえ、そうではなくcmakeを使ってどうやってインクルードできるファイルを生成するのでしょうか？これが知りたいです。